# css 'tab' fix > bottom border of a tab

Tags: html, css, border

@ http://jsfiddle.net/ktCb8/3/ you can see the example.

what do i need to do to get the bottom border on the 'tab' to be WHITE when hovering over one 'tab' (so that the tab over which hover is done is connected to the panel bellow and does not have the gray line).

thnx

latest > http://jsfiddle.net/ktCb8/27/ still cant get it to work :( :(

Comment: It works as you described for Chrome on OS X. What browser is causing problems?

Comment: i pasted how i made it currently > jsfiddle.net/ktCb8/27 but it doesn't work. the line is still there. >> also i am viewing it in latest chrome.

Comment: looks the same in latest internet explorer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just amend:

```
#contentBox > li:hover, #contentBox ul
{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

to:

```
#contentBox > li:hover, #contentBox ul
{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ktCb8/15/).

---

**Edited** in response to question in comments:

> That won't put a gray border on the #contentbox ul's bottom though?

It does indeed remove the bottom border from the `ul` as well, to correct that I'd remove the above change, and simply append this new declaration:

```
#contentBox > li:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

As in this [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ktCb8/26/).

Comment: That won't put a gray border on the #contentbox ul's bottom though? Putting it as `border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    background-color: #FFF;` would solve that issue.

Comment: i dont get it. it works at your example, but it does not really work for me?!?!? lol have to check it out some more.

Comment: i pasted how i made it currently > http://jsfiddle.net/ktCb8/27/ but it doesn't work. the line is still there.

Comment: The tabs' side borders extend an extra pixel into the content element in Chrome. I'm not sure what causes the 1px difference between it and FF.

Comment: it happens in internet explorer as well.

Comment: don't really have firefox any more - keep dying with flash on me, so i gave it up :P

Answer (score 1):

Lower the `z-index` of the content element which appears, and set it's `margin-top` to 1 less pixel.

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ktCb8/23/

```
#contentBox > li:hover ul
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-99;
    margin-top:5px;
    display: block;


}
```

EDIT: Or a minor change to David's sample:

```
#contentBox > li:hover, #contentBox ul
{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ktCb8/25/

Comment: This causes the boxes to shift positions when hovered, and also has ragged borders in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: i pasted how i made it currently > jsfiddle.net/ktCb8/27 but it doesn't work. the line is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Since your first example does work fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on OS X, and you are seeing issues with the spacing on Chrome and Explorer on Windows, it is obviously a discrepency in the base browser styles.

First, use [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to make the spacings consistent across browsers. Then adjust the top margin of the content box until the borders align. Be sure to use `z-index: -1` on the content box as in your first example, not a positive value as in your second.

Comment: if it is -1 then the panel is bellow the header stuff so that can't work. and i am using reset.

Comment: Then you're going to have to set the z-index of the header lower and use `position: relative`. If you are using reset, why didn't use you use it in your examples? The basic answer is the same: fiddle with the margin.