# Hide the bottom border of a selected Tab in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I have a horizontal HTML tab , where i wish to make the bottom border of the selected tab hidden.

Here is the current code i have - https://jsfiddle.net/vgx2k7p5/

The question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180763/css-tab-fix-bottom-border-of-a-tab) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307747/how-do-i-remove-the-bottom-border-of-my-selected-tab)

But both the solutions are not working , since i'm using a div structure and no much javascript.

```js
jQuery('.tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {

  var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

  jQuery(currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide(); //changed here
  jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
/*----- Tab Links -----*/

/* Clearfix */

.tab-links:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
.tab-links {
  margin: 0px;
}
.tab-links li {
  margin: 0px 3px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.tab-links a {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #999;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.tab-links a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*background: #f1f1f1;*/
  /*border-bottom: 4px solid #999;  */
}
li.active a,
li.active a:hover {
  /* border-bottom: 4px solid #444;  */
  /*background: #ccc;*/
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #444;
}
/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/

.tab-content {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 300px;
  z-index: -99;
}
.tab {
  display: none;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.tab.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs margintop20">
  <ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">PROFILE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">REVIEWS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">REWARDS</a>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active clearfix">


    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab">

    </div>

    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
      <h3>Videos and Screenshots</h3>

    </div>


  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

What am i doing wrong here ? Both setting the Z-index and increasing the border-bottom width did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your css with that :

```css
/* ADDED */
.tab-links .active{
    margin-top : 1px;
}
.active > a {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

And now it seems to be working !

---

```js
jQuery('.tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {

  var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

  jQuery(currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide(); //changed here
  jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
/*----- Tab Links -----*/

/* Clearfix */

.tab-links:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
.tab-links {
  margin: 0px;
}
.tab-links li {
  margin: 0px 3px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.tab-links a {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #999;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.tab-links a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  /*background: #f1f1f1;*/
  /*border-bottom: 4px solid #999;  */
}
li.active a,
li.active a:hover {
  /* border-bottom: 4px solid #444;  */
  /*background: #ccc;*/
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #444;
}



/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/

.tab-content {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 300px;
  z-index: -99;
}
.tab {
  display: none;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.tab.active {
  display: block;
}


/* ADDED */
.tab-links .active{
  margin-top : 1px;
  }
.active > a {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs margintop20">
  <ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">PROFILE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">REVIEWS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">REWARDS</a>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active clearfix">


    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab">

    </div>

    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
      <h3>Videos and Screenshots</h3>

    </div>


  </div>
</div>

</div>
```